# Row alignment in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to align my some widgets in a row in a particular way. I want the Icon to be at the beginning of the row and the text to be at the center, I tried wrapping the text widget in a center widget but that didn't work. Please how can I carry out something like that with a row that only has two children?

Comment: You can use `Expand` Widget under `Row` Widget for Text like LogIn etc...

Comment: below answer will provide the look, if you like to point exact center, use transform widget to replace a text a little

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the `Center` in an `Expanded`. So something like this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Row(children: const [
    Icon(Icons.abc),
    Expanded(child: Center(child: Text('abc')))
  ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Stack` for the same

Sample code

```
Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 18),
      color: Colors.black,
      child: Stack(
        children: const [
          Center(
            child: Text(
              "Login",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.white,fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            left: 12,
            child: Icon(
              Icons.close,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```